# Mongo aggregation Match multiple values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following documents

```
  {
       name: 'John',
       Address :'street 1 '
   },
   {
       name: 'Jane',
       Address :'street 2 '
   },
   {
       name: 'Smith',
       Address :'street 3 '
   }
```

I want to search the multiple document with different vales in mongo aggregation pipeline.

That means `name =('John','Smith')`. I'm expecting result is

```
{
   name: 'John',
   Address :'street 1 '
},
{
   name: 'Smith',
   Address :'street 3 '
}
```

My code is

```
db.articles.aggregate($match: { $or: [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Smith' }]);
```

This is giving an empty value.is it possible to get document like this way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use operator the `$in`

> ***The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field***
>   ***equals any value in the specified array.***

```
[{
    $match: {
        name: {
            $in: ['John', 'Smith']
        }
    }
}]
```

Reference: [MongoDB Docs: $in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: Works like a charm. I intend to use this approach for handling filter conditions coming from URL params.